# AngularJS - Adding controller files triggering uncaught error

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am creating an angularJS app, and decided to separate the controllers into multiple files. This is what I have:

For declaring the module, I have one file with the below content:

File: controllers.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', []);
```

and one of the other controllers I am using is called ConnectionsController:
File: ConnectionsController.js

```
angular.module('starter').controller('ConnectionsController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

}]);
```

In the app.js, I have the following:
File: app.js

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'ConnectionsController','starter.MoreOptionsController','starter.OrdersController', 'starter.ProfileManagementController', 'starter.UserAccessController', 'starter.services']);
```

When I run the application, it triggers an error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ConnectionsController due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ConnectionsController' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

What am I doing wrong in declaring the controllers or linking them to app.js file?

Thanks,

Update: Index.html content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ConnectionsController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/OrdersController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you declare your new file in index.html?

Comment: So the error is clear: there is no module `ConnectionsController`, which is obvious from what you posted.

Comment: @wdoering forgot to do that actually but just did by using <script src="js/ConnectionsController.js"></script> and it didn't work.

Comment: @dfsq as I understand, the module is called starter in my case and ConnectionsController is the controller's name. Any recommendation on how to fix this if I am mistaken?

Comment: Can you add script block implementation?

Comment: @ksa_coder good, now make sure it is accessible. I've had a few problems with this so run your application on chrome and make sure your new file is accessible on the sources tab(in chrome developer tools).

Comment: @SharikovVladislav not familiar with script block implementation....

Comment: Can you please update the question with your code in `index.html`. I mean the part where you actually injecting all your script files.

Comment: @Achu added the index file content

Comment: Add your app.js after services,js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory: you don't have module `ConnectionsController`. Note, that when you declare main application module like

```
angular.module('starter', [
    'ionic', 
    'starter.controllers', 
    'ConnectionsController', 
    // etc ... 
]);
```

it means that module `starter` depends on several other modules, in your case `ionic`, `starter.controllers`, `ConnectionsController`. However, `ConnectionsController` is the controller name it's not a module. So you don't have to list it as module dependency.

Comment: Great...it worked now that the errors here disappeared but magically some other error is appearing due to change which is: Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'UserAccessController' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: Never mind, got it working :) Thanks for helping out.